# Android Compose - application on tablets crashes when using a LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nesting scrollable in the same direction layouts like ScrollableContainer and LazyColumn is not allowed. If you want to add a header before the list of items please take a look on LazyColumn component which has a DSL api which allows to first add a header via item() function and then the list of items via items().*

This error always appears on tablets when trying to use LazyColumn. LazyColumn is working correctly on phones. The error appears even when the Composable function in setContent consists only of LazyColumn.

Studio Build: Android Studio 4.2 beta 6 / Canary 10
Version of Gradle Plugin: 4.2.0-beta06 / 7.0.0-alpha10
Version of Gradle: 6.8.3 / 6.8.2
Version of Compose: 1.0.0-beta02 (1.0.0-beta01 has the same issue)

Comment: Can you please provide code.

Comment: Check that you don't use a scrollable component (i.e uses `verticalScroller` modifier or similar) as a parent of your `LazyColumn`

Comment: @kugemi did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and @MR3YY's comment solved my problem. I had a lazyColumn:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
    items(myDs){ dev ->
        deviceView(device = dev)
    }

}
```

and removing the verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) fixed the error.

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    items(myDs){ dev ->
        deviceView(device = dev)
    }

}
```

Comment: what's with verticalScroll? I have the same weird issue

Comment: @JimOvejera you cant use, not height constrained lazycolumn inside vertical scroll since both of them have dynamic height, on calculation, it will throw infinite height error